# How to update/refresh javascript variables data just on a button click, without refreshing the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a javascript file named `roles.js` which contains user roles that I will constantly be adding or removing names from it. I have main javascript file where I call those variables.

The reason why I moved the role variables into a new file is just so it's easier for me to add or remove names without messing with the rest of the code if I were to do this inside my main js file.

These are the role variables:

```
//role
let hostRole = [
    "john" // these are the user names
]

let adminRole = [
    "sarah",
    "amy"
]

let modRole = [
    "megan"
]
```

So every time I add or remove user names, in the `role.js` file, I will need to refresh my website in order for it to take effect.

Is it possible to have a button in my HTML page that refreshes the above javascript file/variables? So I don't have to refresh the webpage all the time.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could show me the code to achieve this. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  You're updating the values in your code?  (e.g. something like `hostRole.push("some name");`)  But somewhere in your code that update isn't shown?  Or do you mean you're actually editing this file on the server in a text editor?  Or something else?  Please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain better but let me try again. So on my site, I have roles, like admin, moderator, and host. Every role has its own privileges. I will be regularly removing or adding new user names. So every time I do the changes, for it to take effect on the site, I will have to reload the page. My question is simply how can I update the changes I made on the roles without reloading the website?

Comment: *"I will be regularly removing or adding new user names."* - Are you doing this in the code on the page?  Are you doing this by directly editing the code file on the server?  Something else?

Comment: in the code, the 'role.js'.

Comment: If you're changing the code server-side then the client doesn't really have any way to know that.  You could have the client-side code regularly check the server for updates via AJAX polling.  Or you could have a server-side application which pushes data to the client using web sockets.  But changing a file on a server does not by itself notify any client that has ever accessed that file.

Answer (score 1):

This question has answers, not as a hole but as parts. If I understand your problem correctly, you need to create 2 functions. One to add a person to targeted array, one to remove a person from targeted array. Those functions should include event listener and specific array methods.
I've created those functions, I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Function to add:

```
const addOnClick =(person, array)=>{
 const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn-id");
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    arr.push(person);
});
```

};

You need to create a button with "add-btn-id" id

function to remove:

```
const removeOnClick =(person,arr)=>{
    const removeBtn = document.getElementById("remove-btn-id")
    removeBtn.addEventListener("Click",function(){
        const i = arr.indexOf(person);
        if(i> -1) arr.splice(i,1);
       });
   };
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I actually have little to zero knowledge of coding. May I know where exactly to put this code and do I have to modify anything so it fits with my current code?

Comment: You can use it as it is. If you have the buttons and right ids. If I were you, I wouldn't use the code directly though. To learn coding, you need to deal with the problems and find your own way. If you still want to use these codes directly, you need to call the functions. For example let's say you want to add "Richard" to hostRole, all you need to is is: addOnClick("Richard", hostRole); You need to creaete an addBtn (button) with an id "add-btn-id" .